# foreach loop on 3 key value array at the same time

Tags: php, laravel

In my database I have a list of pdf categories;
For each category I have a folder with the same name in user folders;
The user can upload pdfs for a specific user from a page where a textbox gets created for each category in database
I need to loop on every folder and check if the name of the folder is equal to that of the category and if it is true store the pdf in that folder

The code I have wrote is this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'form.*' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,csv,txt,pdf',
    ]);

    $Operatore = Operatore::find($request->idOperatore);
    $CategoriePdf = CategoriePdf::all();
    $files = $request->file('photo');
    $path = 'operatori/' . $Operatore->nome . '-' . $Operatore->cognome . '/pdf/';
    $directories = Storage::directories($path);
    if($request->hasfile('form')){
        foreach($CategoriePdf as $Categoria){
        foreach($request->file('form') as $file){
        foreach ($directories as $dir){
                        if($dir == $path . $Categoria->descrizione)
                            $file->store($path . $Categoria->descrizione);
                        
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

As is right now it loops on every folder and adds all the pdfs to every folder
The problem is that those 3 foreach one after another
all the associative array should be equal beetween themself so isnt it possible to iterate on all 3 of them with a single loop?

Edit:
This is the code of the view that uploads the pdfs

```
 <p>Inserisci pdf per l operatore {!!$operatore->nome!!}</p>
<form method="POST" action="pdf/add" style="display:inline" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf

@foreach ($categorie as $categoria)
    <x-adminlte-input-file name="form[{{$categoria->descrizione}}]" igroup-size="sm" placeholder="{!!$categoria->descrizione!!}">
        <x-slot name="prependSlot">
            <div class="input-group-text bg-lightblue">
                <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
            </div>
        </x-slot>
    </x-adminlte-input-file>
@endforeach
    <input type="hidden" name=idOperatore value="{{$operatore->id}}">
    <x-adminlte-button label="invia" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

As you can see a textfield gets added for each row in category table and It gets the name form[$categoria->descrizione] and it gets passed as if it was an array
The problem is that the user can add categories so for each category that they add another text input is created with a name that I cant know
So I made that if to check if any of the directories name is equal to  one of the categories sent in the form

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $validated = $request->validate([
    'descrizione' => 'required|max:255',
    'categoria' => 'required|boolean',
    ]);
    
    $CategoriePdf = new CategoriePdf;
    $normalized_Descrizione = Str::of($validated['descrizione'])->lower()->trim()->replace(' ', '-'); 
    $CategoriePdf->descrizione = $normalized_Descrizione;
    $CategoriePdf->per_veicolo = $validated['categoria'];
    $CategoriePdf->save();

    if($validated['categoria'] == '0')
    {
        $directories = Storage::directories('veicoli');
        foreach ($directories as $directory)
            Storage::makeDirectory($directory ."/pdf/" . $normalized_Descrizione);
    }
    else
    {
        $directories = Storage::directories('operatori');
        foreach ($directories as $directory)
            Storage::makeDirectory($directory ."/pdf/" . $normalized_Descrizione);     
    }
```

This is the code to add a category and it adds a folder with the category name in all of the users pdf/ folder
The problem is that I need to upload every pdf in the right folder

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem, but why do the last foreach? Why not simply do `$file->store(...)`?

Comment: I didn't understand you problem, and agree with Vincent. If there is a folder for each category, why do you need looping through all folders, just give the folder path by using category name.

Comment: Because I dont know how the user will call the category as you can see in the edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved like this:

```
if($request->hasfile('form')){ //form is an associative array of N textInput
$input = $request->all('form');
$Keys = array_keys($input['form']); //we get the name of all array keys because we dont know their name or how many they are as they are generated as the user adds categories in the database
foreach($Keys as $Key)
    $storagePath = Storage::put($path . $Key ,$input['form'][$Key]); //as we loop on key we get the value of the textInput with name form[$key] and store its value
}
```